# React animating a new element in a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a react app that shows linked lists like [this](https://visualgo.net/en/list). I would like to get the animation on my arrow <span>.

```
class Main extends Component {
    state = {
        list: [1,2,3,4,5],
        currentValue: '',
    }
    newElementHandler = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        currentValue: e.target.value
      })
    }
    submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
          list: [...this.state.list, this.state.currentValue],
          currentValue: ''
        });
    }
    render() {
        let showlist = [...this.state.list]
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="list">
                {showlist.map((ele,id)=>(
                    <span>
                        <span className="arrow">--> </span>
                        <span>{ele}</span>
                    </span>
                ))}
                </div>
                <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                    <input value={this.state.currentValue} onChange={this.newElementHandler} />
                    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
                </form>
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Right now, it simply shows the updated list correctly.
Instead, after entering a new element, I want an arrow animation that connects to this new element (like given in the above link). I don't really have an idea about how to implement this. Can someone please help me...Thanks